# Sharing Rule & Child Objects

Tags: apex, sharing

The Object Relationship is as below:
DEAL (Parent, Private) -> WPV (Child) -> Check List (G Child)

The checklist Grand Child Object has a Field called Governance Lead which looks up to the standard User Object.

I would like to share the Check List record with the User chosen in Governance Lead Field automatically when the record is saved. Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest answer - can you dump the "Governance Lead" and use standard `OwnerId` field ;) You didn't specify if the relationship is done with lookups or master-details (in m-d child objects won't have Owner field). Owner is best as it gives this user full access to the record.

Alternatively... criteria-based sharing won't work so I think you'd have to write a trigger that'd make entries in `Check_List__Share` table. Read about "Apex managed sharing". Just type this phrase into the Apex developer guide and read top 3 topics:

1. [Understanding Sharing](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm)
2. [Sharing a record using Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm) (except in your case sounds like a trigger is better choice than a batch job)
3. [Recalculationg Apex managed Sharing](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_recalc.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...

It is a M-D relationship. I am thinking of the below...

[1] Move Governance Lead Field to DEAL Object
[2] Edit the Relationship Fields on both WPV, CHECKLIST Objects to give Edit access if the user has at-least Read on the parent record.
[3] For Specific Profiles whose Job Function is to only have Edit/Delete access to Child Records, Give only R (out of the CRUD) for the Parent custom Object DEAL while all the CRUD for WPV & CHECKLIST Child Objects
[...]

Comment: [4] Code a trigger to perform operations on DEAL__Share Object granting Read Access to Governance Lead.